# The effect of an EMP on circuits

Tags: electromagnetism

Which of these is the current (also, what about voltage?) induced by an EMP pulse within a circuit most dependent on?

1. The area of the region enclosed by the circuit
2. The orientation of that area with respect to the originating direction of the pulse
3. The total length of the circuit (e.g. a wire with two conductors potentially connected together at the ends has lots of length but not much area enclosed within the loop)

Suppose I were hypothetically trying to shield my computer and an iPhone connected to a USB cable to that computer from a high-altitude nuclear event. Does the thinness of the USB cord allow me to extend the cord outside the computer's Faraday cage and still have it be relatively safe? The phone would need to be in its own Faraday cage in this case, of course. What I'm wondering is if the exposed cable would have voltages induced in it.